# Какие есть способы уменьшения размера файла с JSON сгенерированного скриптом?

Tags: python, json

Eсть скрипт, который генерирует JSON нужного мне формата.

Пример сгенерированного файла:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "area": 1
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [90.00526999999931, -0.004729999999999964],
                    [90.00553999999863, -0.004729999999999964],
                    [90.00526999999931, -0.004459999999999928],
                    [90.00553999999863, -0.004459999999999928]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "area": 81
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [90.00742999999386, -0.002569999999999677],
                    [90.00769999999319, -0.002569999999999677],
                    [90.00742999999386, -0.0022999999999996413],
                    [90.00769999999319, -0.0022999999999996413]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

Проблема в том, что файл, который генерируется скриптом очень большой. Я сгенерировал меньшие файлы, и посчитал, что  полный файл у меня займет примеро 0.5Tb, что очень уж много.

Можно ли как-то с помощью средств Python уменьшить размер файла?

Например, мне достаточно 7 знаков после запятой в каждом элементе типа `[90.00742999999386, -0.002569999999999677]`, что по логике должно уменьшить размер файла.

Есть еще какие-то способы и средства для уменьшения размера файла?

---

**UPDATE:** доп. информация из коментариев:

> JSON нужен для того, чтобы строить области по GEO-координатам. В
>   каждом 'area' есть 4 координаты (4 точки, по которым строим область).
>   Далее, этот файл я использую в Tableau для отображения на карте.

Comment: Самым очевидным решением будет переход к хранению в бинарном файле.

Comment: Можно сжимать файл, `deflate`, думаю, хорошо с этим справится

Comment: мне кажется вам могли бы дать более полезные советы если бы вы объяснили как вы собираетесь использовать данный JSON файл. Вам обязательно нужен JSON формат?

Comment: У жсон есть параметр с которым можно убрать выравнивание..

Comment: @MaxU мне он нужен для того, чтобы строить области по GEO-координатам. В каждом 'area' есть 4 координаты (4 точки, по которым строим область). Далее, этот файл я использую в Tableau для отображения на карте. Примерно так)

Answer (score 2):

`Tableau` умеет читать данные [из многих источников](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/exampleconnections_overview.htm), поэтому стоит рассмотреть возможность сохранять ваши геоданные в одну из бесплатных БД, поддерживающих хранение геоданных, например: `MongoDB`, `PostgreSQL`, `Vertica`, etc.

Если вы решите продолжить использование JSON, то вот несколько советов:

- обратите внимание на ограничение: ["A single JSON object cannot exceed 128 MB"](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_json.htm#tips-for-working-with-json-data)
- сохраняйте JSON файл используя следующие параметры (это самый компактный способ - все содержимое JSN файла будет сохранено в одной строке и без пробелов):

  ```
  json.dum(..., indent=None, separators=(",", ":"), ...)`
  ```

Comment: Не самый компактный. `json.dums(..., indent=None, separators=(",", ":"), ...)` будет ещё компактнее.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, уже реализовано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098624/211923) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Я проверил [внутреннюю реализацию метода](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/json/encoder.py#L223-L243), ответсвенного за представление `float` объектов в JSON и был неприятно удивлен - код устроен очень негибко и не нашел простого и эффективного способа изменить представление `float` чисел в JSON.

Поэтому решил написать собственный класс:

```
from json.encoder import _make_iterencode, c_make_encoder
from json.encoder import *

FLOATSTR = "{:.7f}".format

class CompactEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["separators"] = (",", ":")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, float):
            return FLOATSTR(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.encode(self, obj)

    def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):
        if self.check_circular:
            markers = {}
        else:
            markers = None
        if self.ensure_ascii:
            _encoder = encode_basestring_ascii
        else:
            _encoder = encode_basestring

        def floatstr(o, allow_nan=self.allow_nan,
                _repr=FLOATSTR, _inf=INFINITY, _neginf=-INFINITY):
            if o != o:
                text = 'NaN'
            elif o == _inf:
                text = 'Infinity'
            elif o == _neginf:
                text = '-Infinity'
            else:
                return _repr(o)

            if not allow_nan:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Out of range float values are not JSON compliant: " +
                    repr(o))

            return text


        if (_one_shot and c_make_encoder is not None
                and self.indent is None):
            _iterencode = c_make_encoder(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, self.allow_nan)
        else:
            _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
```

Примеры использования:

```
In [22]: with open(r"c:/temp/normal.json", "w") as f:
    ...:     json.dump(d, f, indent=4)

In [23]: with open(r"c:/temp/compact.json", "w") as f:
    ...:     json.dump(d, f, cls=CompactEncoder)
```

Сравнение размеров получившихся JSON файлов:

```
In [25]: from pathlib import Path

In [26]: Path(r"c:/temp/normal.json").stat().st_size
Out[26]: 1904

In [27]: Path(r"c:/temp/compact.json").stat().st_size
Out[27]: 416

In [28]: Path(r"c:/temp/compact.json").stat().st_size / Path(r"c:/temp/normal.json").stat().st_size
Out[28]: 0.2184873949579832
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил воспользоваться offline утилиткой `jtc` (погуглите `jtc` и `json`).

Табуляция и отступы в JSON нужны только лишь для удобства чтения. Для программных обработчиков пробелы между ключами и значениями абсолютно излишни. Можно хранить JSON совершенно без них, плотно сжав JSON без пробелов и перносов строк.

Так, ваш пример занимает вот столько символов (предположим он находится в файле `file.json`):

```
bash $ <file.json cat | wc -c
    1035
bash $
```

Убрав все пробелы он сократится почти вдвое:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -r -t0 | wc -c
     563
bash $
```

Ну и конечно же дальнейшее сжатие можно произвести обрубив все цифоровые значения до 7 знаков после точки:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<^-?\d+\.\d{1,7}>D:' -u0 -T'{$0}' -rt0 | wc -c
     417
bash $
```

Кстати, если нужно внести изменения сразу в исходный файл, то можно воспользоваться ключиком `-f`:

```
bash $ jtc -w'<^-?\d+\.\d{1,7}>D:' -u0 -T'{$0}' -rt0 -f file.json 
bash $ cat file.json | wc -c
     417
bash $
```